# how to refresh token on google oauth2 using firebase functions?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

I developed an integration using Google Oauth2 inside firebase functions to access Google Sheets API. The integration works correctly but I'm having problems to make sure the refresh token is running correctly. The function stops working after the first token expires.

when this happens the following error occur:

```
Function execution started
Error: No refresh token is set.
    at OAuth2Client.refreshTokenNoCache (/workspace/node_modules/googleapis-common/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:161:19)
    at OAuth2Client.refreshToken (/workspace/node_modules/googleapis-common/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:142:25)
    at OAuth2Client.getRequestMetadataAsync (/workspace/node_modules/googleapis-common/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:256:28)
    at OAuth2Client.requestAsync (/workspace/node_modules/googleapis-common/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:329:34)
    at OAuth2Client.request (/workspace/node_modules/googleapis-common/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:323:25)
    at createAPIRequestAsync (/workspace/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:292:27)
    at Object.createAPIRequest (/workspace/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:43:9)
    at Resource$Spreadsheets$Values.update (/workspace/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/apis/sheets/v4.js:601:37)
    at exports.loadStripeData.functions.runWith.https.onRequest (/workspace/index.js:176:32)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I want to make sure the token refresh correctly and get stored on Firestore.

What am I doing wrong?

index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const sheets = google.sheets('v4');
admin.initializeApp();

const CLIENT_ID     = 'CLIENT_ID';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRETT';
const REDIRECT_URL  = 'https://us-central1-MY-PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/oauth2callback';
const SCOPES        = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];

oauth2Client.on('tokens', (tokens) => {
  if (tokens.refresh_token) {
    try {
      admin.firestore()
        .collection('oauth2')
        .doc('google')
        .set({
          tokens: tokens.refresh_token,
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  }
});

/*asks user permission to access his spreadsheets*/
exports.authenticate = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const authorizeUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES.join(','),
  });

  res.send(`<html>click here: <a href="${authorizeUrl}">${authorizeUrl}</a></html>`)
});

/*callback function for when the user finishes authenticating*/
exports.oauth2callback = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
  const code = req.query.code.toString() || '';

  try {
    await admin.firestore()
      .collection('oauth2')
      .doc('google')
      .set({
        code: decodeURIComponent(code)
      });
  } catch(error) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(error))
  }

  res.send('auth successfully. You can close this tab');
});

/* get token from Firestone to execute function*/
async function oauth2Auth() {
  const doc = await admin.firestore()
    .collection('oauth2')
    .doc('google')
    .get();
  const credentials = doc.data();

  if (credentials.code !== undefined) {
    const response = await oauth2Client.getToken(credentials.code);
    credentials.tokens = response.tokens;
    delete credentials.code;

    try {
      await admin.firestore()
        .collection('oauth2')
        .doc('google')
        .set({
          tokens: credentials.tokens,
        })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  oauth2Client.setCredentials(credentials.tokens);
}

/*function that requires google sheets api*/
exports.mainFunction = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
  oauth2Auth();
  //do main function
});
```

Comment: So what happens exactly? you try to refresh token and it doesn't get refreshed? Try adding logging to see which part is not executed? Also maybe `await oauth2Auth();` is needed.

Comment: Thanks @EmilGi, just edited the question with the error log. The function tools almost 9min to execute so I didn't put the `await` since I know it will have to time load the token before it's needed. But if I put the `await` the same problem happens

Comment: The [Oauth2Client Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#handling-refresh-tokens) will automatically handle the `refresh_token` for you when this is about to expire. This [GitHub thread](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/290#issuecomment-366778656) mentions that retrying a 400s error code can cause trouble and this other [GitHub thread](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/pull/307) points a solution. Are you receiving any 400s error codes and thus retrying? Does your function work correctly before the token expires?

Comment: Hi @silopis. The function works correctly before the token expires. I'm doing manually right now: I have to refresh the token manually once per day. But it's not ideal and not scalable. Didn't figure out how to solve it, thinking that the firebase function may not be active when the token needs to be renewed so maybe guarantee that the function is running more often may solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally discovered the problem!

You only get the refreshing token in the first time you ask for authorization. So if you're don't save it correctly you have to ask permission again.

To solve it:

when redirecting the user to the authorization URL add the following parameters to have sure you get the refreshing token:

`access_type=offline&prompt=consent`

to save the refreshing token:

```
oauth2Client.on('tokens', async(tokens:any) => {
    if (tokens.refresh_token) {
      try {
        const authorization = await oauth2Client.getToken(tokens.refresh_token);

        await admin.firestore()
          .collection('collectionName')
          .doc(docId)
          .update({
            token: authorization.tokens
          })
          
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    }
  });
```