# How to handle refresh token in Firebase Function using ExpressJS

Tags: firebase, express, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, refresh-token

I am working on a shipping tool for our store using a Firebase function.  When the shopper requests shipping rates in the cart, the store makes a POST request to our Firebase endpoint with items and address info.  The Firebase function "packages" these items, sends the data to a 3rd party shipping API for rates, and returns the rates to the cart.  My question is how to handle the refresh token for the 3rd party API.  Our access token expires in 15 minutes.  Our store typically only sees a couple dozen shoppers a day, but the cart and checkout pages both make the POST request on each page load.  I can think of two methods to handle the refresh token and don't know what is best.

1. For every request to the 3rd party API, request a new access token first.
2. Each time our Firebase endpoint is called, check the current time against a time and token logged in a Firebase database.  If the time has expired, request a new token before requesting 3rd party rates.

The first is obviously easier, but most of this is new to me so I have no idea of performance differences or if there is a common solution to this problem.

Comment: You need those access/refresh tokens to use the 3rd party API right? I mostly use option 2 as I don't need do periodically run another function to keep token updated especially when the traffic is low. The first request might fail in this case if the token is expired unless you check if the token has expired before the API request is made. This is can be done by checking the exp claim if the token is a JWT.

Comment: @Dharmaraj, thank you for responding.  Yes, I need the access token to use the 3rd party API.  I don't understand the reason you gave for why you use option 2.  If traffic is low, doesn't that mean that each request is more likely to need a new token since more time has passed since the last time the token was used?  Also, in which scenario would the first request fail?  Option 1 gets a new token every time; Option 2 gets a new token if the current time is greater than the databased expiration time.  Yes, the token is JWT with an exp of 15 minutes (900).

Comment: Have you check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62187136/how-to-refresh-token-on-google-oauth2-using-firebase-functions)? Additionally, you can check the response of @sllopis in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments.  I ended up using the jsonwebtoken node to decode the access token to get the expiration time.  The access token, exp, and refresh token are logged in firebase.  A middleware function checks the time of a request against the entry in the database and requests a new access token if necessary.  In case it helps anyone who comes across this:

```
const rp = require("request-promise");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

let exp = "untested";
const document = admin.firestore().collection("tokens").doc("***");

function decodeExp(t) {
const jsonToken = jwt.decode(t);
    decExp = jsonToken.exp;
}

async function tokenTest(req, res, next) {
const tokenEntry = await document.get();
const tokenData = tokenEntry.data();
const now = Date.now() / 1000;
if (now < tokenData.exp) {
    req.token = tokenData.access_token;
    next();
} else {
    const options = {
        url: "***/oauth/token",
        method: "POST",
        json: true,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: {
            grant_type: "refresh_token",
            client_id: "***",
            client_secret: "****",
            refresh_token: tokenData.refresh_token,
        },
    };
    async function newToken(o) {
        try {
            const response = await rp(o);
            const aToken = response.access_token;
            req.token = aToken;
            decodeExp(aToken);
            const updated = new Date().toString();
            const entry = { access_token: aToken, exp: decExp, updated: updated };
            await document.update(entry);
            next();
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Error:", err);
        }
    }
    newToken(options);
}
}
```